EAS build failing but works on Expo go
I am trying to build an app for android using EAS which does work when running on Expo Go app but once I build it I get:
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.
Process 'command 'node'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

and I get this:
> Task :app:createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets
SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 138122586
SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 138122586
at JSON.parse (\<anonymous\>)

I have already tried re-installing all the packages but that did not work.
I am unable to understand this issue thanks in advance for your help.
